# Maven doesn't rewrite property on JUnit/Mockito's context.xml

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit, mockito

I'm running a JUnit Test with Spring and Mockito, and I have an injectable bean with the following configuration:

```
<bean name="roleDefault" id="roleDefault" class="java.lang.String">
  <constructor-arg>
    <value>${database.rule}</value>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

And my pom.xml has this configuration in a profile with an id of "desenvolvimento":

```
<database.rule>SET ROLE RO_APP IDENTIFIED BY WEBAPP</database.rule>
```

The problem is: Either running all the tests in Eclipse or with `mvn test` doesn't compute the value of `${database.rule}`, resulting in the following error:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "${database.rule}" [42000-165]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:181)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.checkRunOver(JdbcConnection.java:1318)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.translateSQL(JdbcConnection.java:1271)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.translateSQL(JdbcConnection.java:1187)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
    ... 75 more
```

Why doesn't maven rewrite the value of `database.rule`?

Comment: Because it shouldn't... The `${...}` in a context file are property placeholders that are replaced by spring not by maven.

Comment: The base test is also annotated with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`

Comment: That still doesn't let maven replace things. I strongly suggest a read of the sprnig docs. Add a `<context:property-placeholder />` which loads a properties file which in turn will replace the `${...}` placeholders.

Comment: Broke all the tests.
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'from.email.default' in string value "${from.email.default}"
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)`

Comment: With Eclipse and `mvn test`

Comment: You have to make sure that all placeholders are replaced...

Comment: Like this at the context.xml? `<bean name="fromEmailDefault" id="fromEmailDefault" class="java.lang.String">
  <constructor-arg>
   <value>${from.email.default}</value>
  </constructor-arg>
 </bean>`

And this at the pom.xml? `<from.email.default>xxx@xxx.com.br</from.email.default>`

Comment: I can't tell what's missing. The application and the tests were all running since march... I only had this problem now. Does it have something to do with the profile?

Comment: can you show the filtering configuration or the one from the resources plugin? does "mvn package" executed on the command line filter the context.xml? Only within the IDE its not working?

Comment: Hmm you are using maven to replace properties, ugh. I would strongly recommend using Spring to do it for you, saves you building a new artifact for each environment. But in this case add the property to the list of properties to replace (and remove the earlier added placeholder).

Comment: Hard to know without seeing what resource filtering is configured in maven for that profile.  Did you set the profile e.g. mvn clean test -P desenvolvimento - or is that profile active by default etc. etc..

Comment: Thanks @DavidVictor and wemu, your solutions worked alongside with Mithun 's.

Comment: @ViniciusPires Glad it worked. I use maven properties with Spring all the time.  Its important to keep clear the distinction between build time properties (maven) and runtime (Spring). Both can work fine together with the maven resource filtering setup correctly & both use the same syntax ${...} http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html - although Spring SPEL can do more sophisticated things of course. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the location of the XML configuration file is included in the resource filter of pom.xml.

`<resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <includes>
    <include>**/*.xml</include>
    </includes>
</resource>`

Comment: It worked! I totally forgot about that... Thanks a lot!